# Airflow Scheduler is continuously issuing warning when using postgresSQL 12 as backend database

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

While executing `airflow scheduler` is continue printing following messages and tasks are NOT getting picked up.

```
[2020-02-21 09:21:20,696] {dag_processing.py:663} WARNING - DagFileProcessorManager (PID=11895) exited with exit code -11 - re-launching
[2020-02-21 09:21:20,699] {dag_processing.py:556} INFO - Launched DagFileProcessorManager with pid: 11898
[2020-02-21 09:21:20,711] {settings.py:54} INFO - Configured default timezone <Timezone [UTC]>
[2020-02-21 09:21:20,725] {settings.py:253} INFO - settings.configure_orm(): Using pool settings. pool_size=5, max_overflow=10, pool_recycle=1800, pid=11898
[2020-02-21 09:21:22,701] {dag_processing.py:663} WARNING - DagFileProcessorManager (PID=11898) exited with exit code -11 - re-launching
[2020-02-21 09:21:22,704] {dag_processing.py:556} INFO - Launched DagFileProcessorManager with pid: 11905
[2020-02-21 09:21:22,712] {settings.py:54} INFO - Configured default timezone <Timezone [UTC]>
[2020-02-21 09:21:22,722] {settings.py:253} INFO - settings.configure_orm(): Using pool settings. pool_size=5, max_overflow=10, pool_recycle=1800, pid=11905
[2020-02-21 09:21:24,704] {dag_processing.py:663} WARNING - DagFileProcessorManager (PID=11905) exited with exit code -11 - re-launching
[2020-02-21 09:21:24,706] {dag_processing.py:556} INFO - Launched DagFileProcessorManager with pid: 11907
[2020-02-21 09:21:24,717] {settings.py:54} INFO - Configured default timezone <Timezone [UTC]>
[2020-02-21 09:21:24,728] {settings.py:253} INFO - settings.configure_orm(): Using pool settings. pool_size=5, max_overflow=10, pool_recycle=1800, pid=11907
[2020-02-21 09:21:26,710] {dag_processing.py:663} WARNING - DagFileProcessorManager (PID=11907) exited with exit code -11 - re-launching
```

Setup: PostgreSQL 12 as backend database with airflow v1.10.9.

But if I change to PostgreSQL 11 scheduler runs as expected. Does any one faced same issue?

Answer (score 0):

is there any particular reason you want to use Postgres ver 12? As of writing this post, Postgresql ver 12 is not supported by 1.10.x.

According to its github page, 
Apache Airflow is tested with:

Master version (2.0.0dev)
Python versions: 3.6, 3.7
Postgres DB: 9.6, 10
MySQL DB: 5.7
Sqlite - latest stable (it is used mainly for development purpose)

Stable version (1.10.9)
Python versions: 2.7, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7
Postgres DB: 9.6, 10
MySQL DB: 5.6, 5.7
Sqlite - latest stable (it is used mainly for development purpose)

Comment: It was to test airflow with pgsql12