# Airflow scheduler fails to start tasks

Tags: postgresql, airflow, airflow-scheduler, postgresql-12

**My problem:**

Airflow scheduler is not assigning tasks.

**Background:**

I have Airflow running successfully on my local machine with sqlitedb. The sample dags as well as my custom DAGs ran without any issues.
When I try to migrate from sqlite database to Postgres (using [this](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howto/initialize-database.html) guide), the scheduler no longer seems to be assigning tasks. The DAG get stuck on "running" state but no task in any DAGs ever gets assigned a state.

**Troubleshooting steps I've taken**

- The web server and the scheduler are running
- The DAG is set to "ON".
- After running airflow initdb, the public schema is populated with all of the airflow tables.
- The user in my connection string owns the database as well as every table in the public schema.

**Scheduler Log**

The scheduler log keeps posting out this WARNING but I have not been able to use it to find any useful information aside form [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60332084/airflow-scheduler-is-continuously-issuing-warning-when-using-postgressql-12-as-b) other post with no responses.

```
[2020-04-08 09:39:17,907] {dag_processing.py:556} INFO - Launched DagFileProcessorManager with pid: 44144
[2020-04-08 09:39:17,916] {settings.py:54} INFO - Configured default timezone <Timezone [UTC]>
[2020-04-08 09:39:17,927] {settings.py:253} INFO - settings.configure_orm(): Using pool settings. pool_size=5, max_overflow=10, pool_recycle=1800, pid=44144
[2020-04-08 09:39:19,914] {dag_processing.py:663} WARNING - DagFileProcessorManager (PID=44144) exited with exit code -11 - re-launching
```

**Environment**

- PostgreSQL version 12.1
- Airflow v1.10.9
- This is all running on a MacBook Pro (Catalina) in a conda virtual environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres was installed using [postgresapp](https://postgresapp.com/). Updated postgresapp to version 2.3.3e. PostgresSQL is still version 12.1 but by updating the postgresapp, the issue was solved.